# How can I set timeout when Client-side streaming GRPC?

Tags: java, spring-boot, stream, timeout, grpc

```
@Override
public StreamObserver<Point> recordRoute(final StreamObserver<RouteSummary> responseObserver) {   

       StreamObserver<RouteSummary> responseObserver = new StreamObserver<RouteSummary>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(RouteSummary summary) {
                    LOGGER.info("Action.");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable t) {
                    LOGGER.error("Error.");
                }
    
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    LOGGER.info("Completed.");
                }
            };
}
```

The project has Grpc Client with JAVA. How can I set timeout after called for any GRPC method like below?

```
rpc RecordRoute(stream Point) returns (RouteSummary) {}
```

Comment: What timeout are you referring to? I guess you probably mean the [deadline](https://grpc.io/blog/deadlines/) of the RPC (i.e., how long to wait for an RPC to complete), which is set on the [Stub](https://javadoc.io/doc/io.grpc/grpc-all/latest/io/grpc/stub/AbstractStub.html) layer.

Comment: Not for stub, I wanna set timeout every calling method.

Comment: Stub is the abstraction to create/make the RPC call and a deadline is tied to the RPC call, so you need to specify the deadline when creating the call. If you want every RPC call to have different deadlines, use `stub.withDeadlineAfter()` to change the deadline setting before making the call. If you are saying you want to set the deadline after the RPC is made (in-flight), that's illy defined.

Comment: As I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63962957/11500161, you can implement a `ClientInterceptor` to set the per-call deadline dynamically. But anyway, it must be set before the call is made, you are not able to change the deadline in the middle of streaming.