# When I must create async stub <GRPC>?

Tags: java, grpc, channel, stub

```
ManagedChannel managedChannel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 8888).usePlaintext().build();
Grpc.Stub stub = CLIGrpc.newStub(managedChannel);
```

When I must create stub? When every method being called or only once?

Answer (score 0):

Only once. Once a stub is created you keep calling methods on it.

Comment: I wanna set timeout every method but the timeout can set for stub, not for method. How can I set timeout for every method?

Comment: CallOptions.withDeadlineAfter() https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/api/src/main/java/io/grpc/CallOptions.java#L139 . You can set CallOptions on any call.

Answer (score 0):

> The Stub layer is what is exposed to most developers and provides type-safe bindings to whatever datamodel/IDL/interface you are adapting.

So you are basically creating one stub for interacting with one remote service. It is the client side interface for invoking the remote service. It is generally recommended to reuse the same Stub for multiple calls.

RPC deadlines are implemented as `CallOptions`, which can be accessed/mutated before the call is sent. If you want to set deadline for each individual RPCs independently, you can implement a [ClientInterceptor](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ClientInterceptor.html) that modifies the call's `CallOptions` with dynamic values. Something similar to

```java
private final AtomicInteger deadlineNano = new AtomicInteger();

class DeadlineAttachingInterceptor implements ClientInterceptor {
  @Override
  public <ReqT, RespT> ClientCall<ReqT, RespT>interceptCall(MethodDescriptor<ReqT, RespT> method,
      CallOptions callOptions, Channel next) {
  return next.newCall(method, callOptions.withDeadlineAfter(deadlineNano.get(), TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS));
}
```